# How can I prevent Cisco AnyConnect VPN from opening on startup?

Tags: mac, applications, startup

[Cisco AnyConnect VPN](https://www.cisco.com/c/en_uk/products/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/index.html) opens whenever I log in and its screen covers everything for a few minutes and can't be minimized. It's really annoying and I'd like to know if there's something, maybe in its `config.plist`, that will prevent it from opening on startup. Does anyone know?

I have to use Cisco AnyConnect for work, so I can't delete it.

Comment: Hey! Can you please check the settings in the app itself for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else comes along with this question, the answer is in the `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.plist` file referenced above. But you don't need to toss that file; instead, just change the RunAtLoad setting at the bottom from true to false:

RunAtLoad

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm pretty sure you can stop apps from opening on startup even though it ignores Login Items. It is most likely in LaunchDaemons.

There are two locations for these, one is for Apple daemons only:

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons

The other is to include 3rd party processes:

> /Library/LaunchDaemons

You may also need to remove from:

> /Library/LaunchAgents

Just remove the files of the app you don't want to launch on startup and it shouldn't show up on launch anymore.

Comment: Regarding the OP's specific app, the culprit seems to be:`/Library/LaunchAgents/com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.plist`. I haven't tested this yet, because an update to the AnyConnect client was just recently released by Cisco and will be percolating downstream shortly.